# No such node json boost

Tags: c++, json, boost

Trying my hardest to figure this out. Take the following header in C++:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <string>

#include "../math/gmath.h"

class json
{
    public:
        json ( std::string filename );
        template <class T> T getData ( std::string key );
    private:
        std::string m_contents;
        boost::property_tree::ptree m_data;
};

template <class T> T json::getData ( std::string key )
{
    return m_data.get<T> ( key );
}
```

And look at the following two JSON files.

I can find all the data just fine from the following JSON.

```
{
    "gameName" : "File and Asset Test 1",
    "displayWidth" : 640,
    "displayHeight" : 480,
    "fullScreen" : false
}
```

But for some reason I get "No such node" on the following JSON.

```
{
    "assetType" : "font",
    "assetName" : "default font",
    "assetFile" : "dat/assets/dfont.png",
    "charMap" : "`1234567890-=~!@#$%^&*()_+qwertyuiop[]\\QWERTYUIOP{}|asdfghjkl;'ASDFGHJKL:\"zxcvbnm,./ZXCVBNM<>? "
}
```

Here is the error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >'
  what():  No such node (assetType)

Thing is, I iterate over the whole thing outputting the keys and values and I see "assetType" in the list! Why is Boost failing to see what is clearly there (And parsed!) and how can I fix this? I looked all over this site and the documentation with no clue where it's going wrong found.

This is the call I made (Strip a bunch of irrelevant parts in the call: InstanceofJSON.getData ( "assetType" );

Comment: [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6854c4646006790b) is an example which runs fine based on your code. Because I can't run it with file stream on coliru, so use a `std::stringstream` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I believe I have it implemented correctly after comparing it with your code. I think I must be failing an index boundary somewhere.

Comment: @jfly I do this all the time: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea055e7dba39ed59

Comment: @sehe Wow, that's really a fantastic way!